# Cakephp email sent but not received

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I am running Cakephp 2.4.3 and am trying to send an email with CakeEmail.

I have this code at the top of my UsersController:

```
App::uses('AppController','Controller','CakeEmail','Network/Email');
```

this function in the Controller:

```
function send_email(){
    try{
        $email = new CakeEmail('test');
        $email->from('sender@example.com');
        $email->to('me@gmail.com');
        $email->subject('Test');
        if($email->send('Test Message'))
            echo 'Success';
        else echo 'Failure without Exception';
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Failure with Exception';
    }
}
```

and this in Config/email.php

```
public $test = array(
  'log' => true
);
```

When I go to the url: mysite.com/users/send_email

it says "Success" and the debug log says:

```
2014-05-30 22:49:43 Debug: 
From: sender@example.com
X-Mailer: CakePHP Email
Date: Fri, 30 May 2014 22:49:43 +0000
Message-ID: <53890b07e3b44b2b88132a62ad2deb05@mysite.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Test Message
```

but I never get an email coming into my Gmail account. I have checked my spam folder as well. What could be the issue and how else can I debug this?

UPDATE:

My cake app is being hosted on the web. I tried using a different email address at a different domain and changing the email code to this:

```
try{
    if(mail('xxx@iioengine.com','Test Subject','Test Message'))
        echo 'Success';
    else echo 'Failure without Exception';
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'Failure with Exception';
}
```

but the result did not change.

Comment: Try using gmail's troubleshooter:  https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2935079

Comment: I just tried another email address I have at a different domain and got the same result

Comment: What transport are you using? For instance, here is my gmail config (which I think worked _I use smtp now via AWSSES_) `public $gmail = array('host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com' ,'port' => 465 ,'username' => 'foo@gmail.com' ,'password' => 'foobar','transport' => 'Smtp');`

Comment: not sure.. whatever Cake defaults to. I originally tried an SMTP setup  but it wasn't working so I simplified it to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending mail generally doesn't work from localhost. You can try and set the port in the settings, but your isp will probably have the port blocked.

Just checking the specs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

It looks like maybe your `new` declaration shouldn't have test inside:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
```

To debug, you could try sending an email to a different host (not gmail). You could also try using the default php `mail()` function, which is actually quite simple to use and very similar to cake's layout, not surprisingly.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I'm not using localhost - its up the web. I tried using mail, but the same thing happened.

Comment: It might be your web host blocking the mail from being sent. Different hosts have different mail restrictions. And sometimes you can be on an ip that is blocked altogether for some reason.

Comment: Ok, I'm not the administrator of the server, so I'll have to check with him

Comment: I got a response saying "I have reconfigured postfix" and the emails now work in both direct php calls and with cakes helpers. Thanks for the debugging tips.